# How to get a distinct count with sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to get a distinct count of a particular column using sequelize.  My initial attempt is using the 'count' method of my model, however it doesn't look like this is possible.

The DISTINCT feature is needed because I am joining other tables and filtering the rows of the parent based on the related tables.

here's the query I would like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Product.id) as `count` 
FROM `Product` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Vendor` AS `vendor` ON `vendor`.`id` = `Product`.`vendorId` 
WHERE (`vendor`.`isEnabled`=true );
```

using the following query against my Product model:

```
Product.count({
        include: [{model: models.Vendor, as: 'vendor'}],
        where: [{ 'vendor.isEnabled' : true }]
    })
```

Generates the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` 
FROM `Product` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Vendor` AS `vendor` ON `vendor`.`id` = `Product`.`vendorId` 
WHERE (`vendor`.`isEnabled`=true );
```

Comment: Why not just use a stored procedure and call it? According to this changelog (http://sequelizejs.com/changelog/v1-6-0) sequelize supports stored procedures. Then you can write the query in a way that's best suited for your needs, and well as optimizing it for the database you're using.

Comment: That could be a valid solution, are you saying there is no other way to include DISTINCT in a count operation?

Comment: I do not know of any other way, but other people may have ideas about a way to do it. In general, I try to use stored procedures for all DB related code for reasons such as this. And I use this approach no matter what front end technology I happen to be using. What's really nice is that then you can re-use that stored procedure as different front-end technologies are used against your DB.

Comment: @Adam how come you love DISTINCT and Sequelize so much?

Comment: @JoshC Because I love to stand out from the crowd.  I'm an iconoclast.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like this is now supported in Sequelize versions 1.7.0+.

the `count` and `findAndCountAll` methods of a model will give you 'real' or 'distinct' count of your parent model.

Comment: I've just recently started using Sequelize, but shouldn't it be `findAndCountAll`? Maybe the method name changed between now and two years ago. Just letting people who see this know.

Answer (score 68):

### UPDATE: New version

There are now separate `distinct` and `col` options. [The docs for `distinct`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-count) state:

> Apply COUNT(DISTINCT(col)) on primary key or on options.col.

You want something along the lines of:

```js
MyModel.count({
  include: ...,
  where: ...,
  distinct: true,
  col: 'Product.id'
})
.then(function(count) {
    // count is an integer
});
```

### Original Post

(As mentioned in the comments, things have changed since my original post, so you probably want to ignore this part.)

After looking at [Model.count method in lib/model.js](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/model.js#L847), and tracing some code, I found that when using `Model.count`, you can just add any kind of aggregate function arguments supported by MYSQL to your options object. The following code will give you the amount of different values in `MyModel`'s `someColumn`:

```js
MyModel.count({distinct: 'someColumn', where: {...}})
.then(function(count) {
    // count is an integer
});
```

That code effectively generates a query of this kind: `SELECT COUNT(args) FROM MyModel WHERE ...`, where `args` are all properties in the options object that are not reserved (such as `DISTINCT`, `LIMIT` and so on).

Comment: Actually the distinct parameter is a boolean parameter, which only indicates if a distinct should be used or not. distinct counts are always applied on the primary key of the model, so this solution will not work accordingly, at least not with the current sequelize version.

Answer (score 13):

The [Sequelize documentation on `count`](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/index.html?highlight=count#countoptions-promiseinteger) links to [a count method](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/f678009d7514b81a6f87e12b86360e9a597e3ca8/lib/model.js#L1344) that doesn't let you specify which column to get the count of distinct values:

```
Model.prototype.count = function(options) {
  options = Utils._.clone(options || {});
  conformOptions(options, this);
  Model.$injectScope(this.$scope, options);
  var col = '*';
  if (options.include) {
    col = this.name + '.' + this.primaryKeyField;
    expandIncludeAll.call(this, options);
    validateIncludedElements.call(this, options);
  }
  Utils.mapOptionFieldNames(options, this);
  options.plain = options.group ? false : true;
  options.dataType = new DataTypes.INTEGER();
  options.includeIgnoreAttributes = false;
  options.limit = null;
  options.offset = null;
  options.order = null;
  return this.aggregate(col, 'count', options);
};
```

Basically `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(*))` or `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(primaryKey))` if you've got a primary key defined.

To do the Sequelize equivalent of `SELECT category, COUNT(DISTINCT(product)) as 'countOfProducts' GROUP BY category`, you'd do:

```
model.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'category',
    [Sequelize.literal('COUNT(DISTINCT(product))'), 'countOfProducts']
  ],
  group: 'category'
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for **SELECT COUNT(0)** query for sequelize,  below is the answer for that.

```
    let existingUsers = await Users.count({
        where: whereClouser,
        attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', 0), 'count']]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to get distinct count from another table rows,

```
dataModel.findAll({
    attributes: { 
        include: [[Sequelize.literal("COUNT(DISTINCT(history.data_id))"), "historyModelCount"]] 
    },
    include: [{
        model: historyModel, attributes: []
    }],
    group: ['data.id']
});
```

[Ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52093394/3411787), [Ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32104023/3411787).

Answer (score 0):

**With respect to your question in order to get the distinct counts of products based on the id of product**

**you just need to pass the key 'distinct' with value 'id' to your count object , Here is the example**

To generate this sql query as you asked

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`Product`.`id`)) as `count` 
FROM `Product` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Vendor` AS `vendor` ON `vendor`.`id` = `Product`.`vendorId` 
WHERE (`vendor`.`isEnabled`=true );
```

Add 'distinct' key in your Sequelize query

```
Product.count({
        include: [{model: models.Vendor, as: 'vendor'}],
        where: [{ 'vendor.isEnabled' : true }],
        distinct: 'id' // since count is applied on Product model and distinct is directly passed to its object so Product.id will be selected
    });
```

This way of using 'distinct' key to filter out distinct counts or rows , I tested in Sequelize Version 6.

Hope this will help you or somebody else!