# Distinct count with sequelize

Tags: node.js, count, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get a distinct count with sequelize such as

```
'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(age)) AS `count` FROM `Persons` AS `Person`'
```

As long as I use a raw query, I get the desired result. However, as soon as I change to the sequelize count function, the query is broke in Postgres:

```
Person.count({distinct:'age'}).then(...);
```

results to

```
'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(*)) AS `count` FROM `Persons` AS `Person`'
```

which leads to a syntax error. Solutions described in different posts such as [How to get a distinct count with sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643263/how-to-get-a-distinct-count-with-sequelize) do not work, unless you add an include statement or a where clause which I do not have in this special case.

Does anybody know a proper solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use Sequelize [aggregation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/?highlight=count#aggregatefield-aggregatefunction-options-promiseoptionsdatatypeobject) to make it worked correctly.

> `Model.aggregate(field, aggregateFunction, [options])`
>
> Returns: Returns the aggregate result cast to options.dataType, unless
>   options.plain is false, in which case the complete data result is
>   returned.

Example:

```
Person.aggregate('age', 'count', { distinct: true })
    .then(function(count) {
      //.. distinct count is here 
    });
```

Executing (default):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT("age")) AS "count" FROM "persons" AS "person";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it something like this :

```
models.User.findAll({
  attributes: ['user_status',[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('user_status')), 'total']] ,
  group : ['user_status']
});
```

That will return something like :

```
[
    { user_status : 1 , total : 2 },
    { user_status : 2 , total : 6 },
    { user_status : 3 , total : 9 },
    ...
]
```

Then you can loop through returned data and check of status

Answer (score 3):

In latest version, you should be doing

```
Person.count({distinct:true, col: 'age'}).then(...);
```

See: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-count

Comment: please update the docs link, not accessible anymore