# Need to count a joined table rows sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using `sequelize` to query on a `sqlserver` database. I have two tables:

```
data: columns - id, name, team, type

history:columns - id, node, date, status, data_id(foreignkey)
```

and a relation

`history.belongsTo(data, {foreignKey: 'data_id'}`

`data.hasMany(history, {foreignKey: 'data_id'})`

My query is:

```
dataModel.findAll({
    attributes: ['name'],
    include: [{
        model:historyModel
    }]
})
```

My result looks like this:

```
[
    {
         name: "1",
         history: [
             {
                 ...
             }
         ]
    },
    {
         name: "2",
         history: [
             {
                 ...
             }
         ]
    }
]`
```

I want that instead of the history array I will have the count of history objects in each one. The query in `sql` is:

```
select data.name, count(history.data_id) count 
from history 
inner join data on data.id=history.data_id 
group by history.data_id, data.name
```

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
dataModel.findAll({
    attributes: { 
        include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("history.data_id")), "historyModelCount"]] 
    },
    include: [{
        model: historyModel, attributes: []
    }],
    group: ['data.id']
});
```

Comment: When i do that i get an error that it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause

Comment: now it says the same about all of the cols of the dataModel
but they are no in the attributes of the dataModel..

Comment: how can i choose the attributes of the dataModel?
it just put all of them and adds the count too

Comment: `Model.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quz', [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("history.data_id")), "historyModelCount"]]
});`

Comment: Ok, I finaly did it!
    `dataModel.findAll({


        attributes: [
            ['name', 'name'], [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('history.data_id')), 'count']
        ],
        include: [
            model: historyModel,
            attributes:[]
        ],
        group: ['data.id','data.name']
    })`