# Sequelize : Count LEFT OUTER JOIN Table Row Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have searched `stackoverflow` for the answer to this, none worked, all throws the same error:
`Unknown column 'contact_label.label_id' in 'field list'`

for example:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52093055/need-to-count-a-joined-table-rows-sequelize`

I wrote and modified the query like the above:

```
            let result = await this._label.findAll({

                where: {
                    user_id: user_id,
                    name: {
                        [Op.like]: '%' + keyword + '%'
                    }
                },

                attributes: {

                    include: [
                        [
                            Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("contact_labels.label_id")), "contactLabelCount"
                        ],
                    ]
                },

                include: [
                    {
                        as: 'contact_labels',
                        model: ContactLabel,
                        required: false,
                        attributes: []
                    }
                ],

                group: [
                    'labels.id',
                    'labels.user_id',
                    'labels.name',
                    'labels.description',
                    'labels.color',
                    'labels.created_at',
                    'labels.updated_at',
                ],
                limit: 10,
            })
```

and it still throws error

here is the raw query it generated:

```
SELECT 
  `labels`.`id`, 
  `labels`.`user_id`, 
  `labels`.`name`, 
  `labels`.`description`, 
  `labels`.`color`, 
  `labels`.`created_at`, 
  `labels`.`updated_at`, 
  COUNT(`contact_label`.`label_id`) AS `contactLabelCount` 
FROM 
  `labels` AS `labels` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `contact_label` AS `contact_labels` ON `labels`.`id` = `contact_labels`.`label_id` 
WHERE 
  `labels`.`user_id` = 1 
  AND `labels`.`name` LIKE '%%' 
GROUP BY 
  `labels`.`id`;
```

Label Table: DB name: `labels`

```
| id | user_id | name | description |
-------------------------------------
|  2 |       1 | Test | Test Desc   |
```

Contact Label Table: DB name: `contact_label`

```
| id | contact_id | label_id |
------------------------------
|  1 |          2 |        2 |
```

Sequelize Relationship:

```
db.contacts.belongsToMany(db.labels, {
    through: db.contactlabel,
    foreignKey: "contact_id",
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});

db.labels.belongsToMany(db.contacts, {
    through: db.contactlabel,
    foreignKey: "label_id",
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});

db.contactlabel.belongsTo(db.contacts, {
    as: 'contact',
    foreignKey: "contact_id",
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});

db.contacts.hasMany(db.contactlabel, {
    as: 'contact_labels',
    foreignKey: "contact_id",
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});

db.contactlabel.belongsTo(db.labels, {
    as: 'label',
    foreignKey: "label_id",
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});

db.labels.hasMany(db.contactlabel, {
    as: 'contact_labels',
    foreignKey: "label_id",
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
});
```

I can get the correct count another way with `sequelize.literal`:

```
                attributes: {

                    include: [
                        [
                            // Unread Count
                            sequelize.literal(`(
                                SELECT COUNT(*)
                                FROM contact_label AS cl
                                WHERE
                                    cl.label_id = labels.id
                            )`),
                            'contactLabelCount'
                        ],
                    ]
                },
```

but I cannot figure out how to add `DISTINCT` to the query

Comment: When you aggregate one column, you have to group by **all** the non-aggregated columns.

Comment: Also note that we have no idea what your `contact_label` table looks like.

Comment: Oh also also in the join you have an `AS` clause that changes the table name to `contact_labels` but you reference the column with `contact_label` in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: I would say that your table does not actually look like what you say it does.  What database are you using? Where's the connection string?

Comment: I am using `MariaDB 10.4.14`

Comment: contact_labels vs contact_label, with or without an extra `s`